# After calling an endpoint using send mediator I am getting the following error response

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

After calling an endpoint using send mediator I am getting the following error response, but when i calling same endpoint using call blocking mediator i can view the response.endpoint is secure one since i can't trace it.

[2020-07-27 17:12:48,307] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-15] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)

**when i change axis2.xml message builder and formatter to text/html my output like following**.

{"binary":"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"}, Content-Type = text/html

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the Content Type of the payload you are sending and check whether the relevant Formatter is used in axis2.xml

Check these issues for reference [WSO2 EI 6.1.1 DOCTYPE is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114823/wso2-ei-6-1-1-doctype-is-not-allowed)
Also this [in wso2 ei i am getting org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503851/in-wso2-ei-i-am-getting-org-apache-axiom-om-omexception-javax-xml-stream-xmlstr/50509602)